# Labelling a grid using n labels, where every label neighbours every other label

Tags: algorithm, matrix, grid, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to create a grid with n separate labels, where each cell is labelled with one of the n labels such that all labels neighbour (edge-wise) all other labels somewhere in the grid (I don't care where). Labels are free to appear as many times as necessary, and I'd like the grid to be as small as possible. As an example, here's a grid for five labels, 1 to 5:

```
3 2 4
5 1 3
2 4 5
```

While generating this by hand is not too bad for small numbers of labels, it appears to be very hard to generate a grid of reasonable size for larger numbers and so I'm looking to write a program to generate them, without having to resort to a brute-force search. I imagine this must have been investigated before, but the closest I've found are De Bruijn tori, which are not quite what I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Benawii for the following improved description:

> "Given an integer n, generate the smallest possible matrix where for every pair (x,y) where x≠y and x,y ∈ {1,...,n} there exists a pair of adjacent cells in the matrix whose values are x and y."

Comment: Hi Geoffrey. Could you, please, describe more explicitly what are your input and output? Eg: Inputs: number of labels, matrix size, ...

Comment: The only input is n, the number of labels. A matrix of any size can be generated, but the smaller the better.

Comment: It's not super clear what you want.Please rewrite the first few lines, to help us help you.

Comment: Do you mean: for all values x and y, they are adjacent somewhere in the matrix.

Comment: The problem is "Given an integer n, generate the smallest possible matrix where for every pair (x,y) where x≠y and x,y ∈ {1,...,n} there exists a pair of adjacent cells in the matrix whose values are x and y."

Comment: Thanks, Benawii, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not too bothered about it being the smallest possible matrix, though, but it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with a simple greedy algorithm.

I don't think that I'm able to give you a strict mathematical prove, at least because the question is not strictly defined, but the algorithm is quite intuitive.

First, if you have 1...K numbers (K labels) then you need at least K*(K-1)/2 adjacent cells (connections) for full coverage. A matrix of size NxM generates (N-1)*M+(M-1)*N=2*N*M-(N+M) connections.

Since you didn't mention what you understand under 'smallest matrix', let's assume that you meant the area. In that case it is obvious that for the given area the square matrix will generate bigger number of connections because it has more 'inner' cells adjacent to 4 others. For example, for area 16 the matrix 4x4 is better than 2x8. 'Better' is intuitive - more connections and more chances to reach the goal. So lets use target square matrixes and expand them if needed. The above formula will become 2*N*(N-1).

Then we can experiment with the following greedy algorithm:

1. For input number K find the N such that 2*N*(N-1)>K*(K-1)/2. A simple school equation.
2. Keep an adjacency matrix M, set M[i][i]=1 for all i, and 0 for the rest of the pairs.
3. Initialize a resulting matrix R of size NxN, fill with 'empty value' markers, for example with -1.
4. Start from top-left corner and iterate right-down:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
           for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
                   R[i][j];
   ```
5. for each such R[i][j] (which is -1 now) find such a value which will 'fit best'. Again, 'fit best' is an intuitive definition, here we understand such a value that will contribute to a new unused connection. For that reason create the set of already filled cell neighbor numbers - S, its size is 2 at most (upper and left neighbor). Then find first k such that M[x][k]=0 for both numbers x in S. If no such number then try at least one new connection, if no number even for one then both neighbors are completely covered, put some number from uncovered here - probably the one in 'worst situation' - such x where Sum(M[x][i]) is the smallest. You should also choose the one in 'worst situation' when there are several ones to choose from in any case.
6. After setting the value for R[i][j] don't forget to mark the new connections with numbers x from S - M[R[i][j]][x] = M[x][R[i][j]] = 1.
7. If the matrix is filled and there are still unmarked connections in M then append another row to the matrix and continue. If all the connections are found before the end then remove extra rows.

You can check this algorithm and see what will happen. Step 5 is the place for playing around, particularly in guessing which one to choose in equal situation (several numbers can be in equally 'worst situation').

Example:

for K=6 we need 15 connections:

N=4, we need 4x4 square matrix. The theory says that 4x3 matrix has 17 connections, so it can possibly fit, but we will try 4x4.

Here is the output of the algorithm above:

```
1234
5615
2413
36**
```

I'm not sure if you can do by 4x3, maybe yes... :)